# How to set the autocomplete to default on each render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete, use-effect

I have accountInfo property which should change targetValue to default.I am using useEffect to achieve the same, but the value targetValue is not reseting to default. What can I do to achieve the same.

The accountInfo property changes on the rendering of the page to a different account. But the targetValue changeValue is not displayed in the Autocomplete. How can I fix the same.

```
   const [targetValue, setTargetValue] = useState({
    value: 0,
    unit: "",
  });
```

```
  const onUnitChange = (
    _event: ChangeEvent<unknown>,
    changeValue: { value: number; unit: string } | null,
  ) => {
    if (changeValue) {
      setTargetValue(changeValue);
    }
  };
```

```
  const valuesIn = Array.from({ length: 10 / 0.25 }, (_, i) =>
    ((i + 1) * 0.25).toFixed(2),
  ).map((itm) => ({ value: Number(itm), unit: "in" }));
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTargetValue({
      value: 0,
      unit: "",
 });
}, [accountInfo]);
```

```
<Autocomplete
                          disablePortal
                          options={(() => {
                            return valuesIn;
                          })()}
                          getOptionSelected={(option, selected) =>
                            option.value === selected.value
                          }
                          defaultValue={{ value: 0, unit: "" }}
                          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value.toString()}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              variant="standard"
                              helperText={unitLabel}
                            />
                          )}
                          onChange={onUnitChange}
                        />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your `usestate`, you need to make it to default initial value. Making it null will won't work.

```
useEffect(() => {
setTargetValue({
  value: 0,
  unit: "",
 });
}, [accountInfo]);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I tried this as well. It did not work. Thank you, Updated the post.

Comment: can you share a sandbox  link to test !